# Autocorrect in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to the XCode environment. Having had development experience with Eclipse & Visual Studio, I was looking for a auto-correct tool in Xcode. Unfortunately, I couldnt find one. Any idea if it exists or how to bring it up?

**Example**

myObject.newField = 2;

Xcode complains the fact that newField does not exist. In visual studio (with resharper) I could hit a shortcut and it would create the new field for me. Or perhaps, create a method that did not exist.

Thanks

**Edit**
To clarify the question, I am trying to use the autocorrect tool as a means to create new vars and methods.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to correct mistakes or create new ivars and methods? Can you clarify the question. Also, what have you tried? Have you read the Xcode docs?

Comment: I have updated the question. I was trying to create new ivars & methods

Comment: The only thing I know of that is anything remotely similar to what your describing is command-clicking on any variable/method and Xcode will show you where it's being referenced from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode does not have the feature you are describing.  It won't offer to create a declaration when you use an undeclared variable or method.

Answer (score 0):

Type in `myObject.` then press "esc" on your keyboard and you'll see a list of properties related to that object